# "-r" parameter affecting duration

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding

Starting with this file:

```
Input #0, flac, from 'alfa.flac':
  Duration: 00:02:52.48, bitrate: 503 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
```

Running this command yields similar output duration, however slow to encode:

```
$ time ffmpeg -loop 1 -i bravo.jpg -i alfa.flac -shortest slow.mp4    
frame= 4371 fps= 46 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4497kB time=00:02:54.76 bitrate= 210.8kbits/s

real    1m34.318s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

I can lower the input framerate which speeds up the encode significantly, but
now the duration is quite off:

```
$ time ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 1 -i bravo.jpg -i alfa.flac -shortest fast.mp4
frame=  232 fps= 31 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2860kB time=00:03:50.00 bitrate= 101.9kbits/s

real    0m7.566s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Can I change my command so that encode speed is decent without messing the
duration?

Comment: I assume this is because you placed `-r` before `-i`, where ffmpeg takes one image every second. What happens when you put `-r` after the `-i` options?

Comment: How do you mean, it doesn't work? Does the command fail? Ideally that'd only change the output frame rate. But yeah, mark4o's suggestion seems reasonable. (Please don't flag comments such as the above as obsolete – they might still be useful to others. Thanks)

Comment: For me, `time` stays at `00:00:00` for a while, but not forever. In any case, it delivers output that's off by a minute or more. Weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `-shortest` with `-t 2:52.48` (i.e. the desired duration).

Unfortunately, `-shortest` is not completely accurate, as it only stops on internal buffer boundaries (which may have a very long duration in the case of 1 fps static looping video).

Comment: True, even without `-r 1`, it's off by more than two seconds for me. Didn't know it was *that* inaccurate.